# must be a structured array with the first field being a binary class RandomSurvivalForest

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am not sure why I am getting the following error.

```
 y must be a structured array with the first field being a binary class event indicator and the second field the time of the event/censoring
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2136632501118727> in <module>
      5                            n_jobs=-1,
      6                            random_state=0)
----> 7 rsf.fit(X_train, y_train)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sksurv/ensemble/forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    235         self
    236         """
--> 237         X, event, time = check_arrays_survival(X, y)
    238 
    239         self.n_features_ = X.shape[1]

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sksurv/util.py in check_arrays_survival(X, y, **kwargs)
    192         Time of event or censoring.
    193     """
--> 194     event, time = check_y_survival(y)
    195     kwargs.setdefault("dtype", numpy.float64)
    196     X = check_array(X, ensure_min_samples=2, **kwargs)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sksurv/util.py in check_y_survival(y_or_event, allow_all_censored, *args)
    132 
    133         if not isinstance(y, numpy.ndarray) or y.dtype.fields is None or len(y.dtype.fields) != 2:
--> 134             raise ValueError('y must be a structured array with the first field'
    135                              ' being a binary class event indicator and the second field'
    136                              ' the time of the event/censoring')

ValueError: y must be a structured array with the first field being a binary class event indicator and the second field the time of the event/censoring
```

I have tried converting the datatype to bool. as well and converting to array
my data looks like this:

```
below   day_of_quarter
0   0   87
1   1   38
2   0   18
3   1   84
4   0   64
```

and here is my code useing a sklearn survival package. The data should be set up for a survival analysis.

```
from sksurv.ensemble import RandomSurvivalForest

df = data.select(col('below'),col('day_of_quarter')).toPandas()
x = df.day_of_quarter
y = df.below.astype(bool)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
rsf = RandomSurvivalForest(n_estimators=1000,
                           min_samples_split=10,
                           min_samples_leaf=15,
                           max_features="sqrt",
                           n_jobs=-1,
                           random_state=0)
rsf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Show the **full traceback/error**.  Also identify what this `RandomSurvivalForest` is. And while you are at it, verify that your arguments match its specifications.  Don't assume that anyone else on SO has worked with this exact problem before!

Comment: Did you read the docs? I shouldn't have to link or  quote the relevant lines!  Do you know what a sfructured array is?

Comment: From the traceback, it's checking if your input is a numpy array, and I don't see anything that suggests it tries to convert first; try just converting your frame to an array (`.values`)?

Comment: thanks you @BenReiniger. Yes, I tried a couple ways, converting the variables (x,y as df[['below']].to_records(index=True)) and the dataframes as a whole (df.to_numpy()). I get the same error no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are your censor and temporal data for RSF:

```
import pandas as pd
below = [0,1,0,1,0]
day_of_quarter = [87, 38, 18, 84, 64]
your_data = pd.DataFrame({'below':below,day_of_quarter':day_of_quarter})
your_data['below'] = your_data['below'].astype(bool)
your_data
```

[image]

You need to create a structured array, that has two fields. You can use to_records() function:

```
y = your_data.to_records(index=False)
y
```

[image]

This is how your 'y' must look like in RandomSurvivalForest.

You haven't provided information on 'x' data, but it must be your input features per patient. It will be a matrix with columns - features (age, sex), rows - patient (1,2,3 patient).